# Can symfony serializer deserialize return nested entity of type child entity?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

When I deserialize my doctrine entity, the initial object is constructed/initiated correctly, however all child relations are trying to be called as arrays.

The root level object's `addChild(ChildEntity $entity)` method  is being called, but Symfony is throwing an error that addChild is receiving an array and not an instance of ChildEntity.

Does Symfony's own serializer have a way to deserialize nested arrays (child entities) to the entity type?

JMS Serializer handles this by specifying a `@Type("ArrayCollection<ChildEntity>")` annotation on the property.

Comment: Hey, did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Symfony serializer attempts to be minimal compared to the JMS Serializer, so you might have to implement your own denormalizer for the class. You can see how [the section on adding normalizers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#adding-normalizers-and-encoders).

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way, but so far with Symfony I am using Discriminator interface annotation and type property for array of Objects. It can also handle multiple types in one array (MongoDB):

```
namespace App\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\DiscriminatorMap;

/**
 * @DiscriminatorMap(typeProperty="type", mapping={
 *    "text"="App\Model\BlogContentTextModel",
 *    "code"="App\Model\BlogContentCodeModel"
 * })
 */
interface BlogContentInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType(): string;
}
```

and parent object will need to define property as interface and get, add, remove methods:

```
    /**
     * @var BlogContentInterface[]
     */
    protected $contents = [];
    
    /**
     * @return BlogContentInterface[]
     */
    public function getContents(): array
    {
        return $this->contents;
    }

    /**
     * @param BlogContentInterface[] $contents
     */
    public function setContents($contents): void
    {
        $this->contents = $contents;
    }

    /**
     * @param BlogContentInterface $content
     */
    public function addContent(BlogContentInterface $content): void
    {
        $this->contents[] = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @param BlogContentInterface $content
     */
    public function removeContent(BlogContentInterface $content): void
    {
        $index = array_search($content, $this->contents);
        if ($index !== false) {
            unset($this->contents[$index]);
        }
    }
```